# Should I connect a small DC motor directly to the mains without an isolation barrier?

Tags: capacitor, ac, dc-motor, mains, safety

I recently found out I'd need to pay upwards of $2k in order to supply my entire house with automated blinds. I feel like I can definitely do it myself for a fraction of the cost.

For this purpose I'm looking into what would be the cheapest way of powering small 2W/3W 12V/24V motors like those ones, which are pretty easy to get a hold of for a couple of bucks:

[image]

I stumbled across [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wzNdIKaNW5E), which shows something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpM8XT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Yes, I replaced the motor with a bulb because I couldn't find a symbol for it, sorry.

As far as I understand, the diode will chop it into a half wave, and the resistor will limit the current to:

$$ 220 / 1.414 / 2 / 1000000 = 77 uA $$

Which would probably not be enough to do any work, but let's say I can replace the resistor with a 500 ohm one to get around 155mA, or whatever other value it needs to be in case my calculations are incorrect.

Yes, I'm aware that the produced voltage will not be DC but it should be OK as in it won't introduce damage the motor, and yes, I will need to add a couple of relays between the motor and diode/resistor to be able to switch the direction. I'm really just looking for the cheapest working solution.

I'm not sure what the purpose of the capacitor is and what its value has to be.

Comment: No, stop before you set fire to your house, and electrocute yourself. For 12V/24V motors, buy 12 V or 24 V power supplies, off the shelf, CE / UL marked for safety.

Comment: Do NOT attempt testing this circuit. It screams personal injury if you're not familiar with line voltage and its dangers. Search for Arduino + DC motor control applications. There are plenty of tutorials and off-the-shelf kits to control DC motors. This will be much safer and even fun.

Comment: Cellphone charger wall warts are super cheap sources of 5V/1A - would you consider a 5V motor?

Comment: @DanielMelendrez well I've done that bunch of times and it would be definitely more fun doing it this way, minus setting my house on fire. Also kits are quite overpriced, the parts above cost cents, if only it is possible to avoid fire of course.

Comment: @Bryan perhaps, but I'm trying to learn something new as well.

Comment: $2k sounds like a bargain to me. Unless you place no value on your own time, and have low standards about safety and how the final installation will look. Not to mention that if you don't know what the capacitor is for, you're way outside your skillset for this job.

Comment: @php_nub_qq it's up to you. No responsible EE around here would approve such a hazardous solution. Not only do you risk yourself, you will end up burning several motors which in the end will defeat your purpose of saving money. Follow what Bryan said at the very least. Use a DC power supply. Motor shields for Arduino are readily available and easy to code.

Comment: @DaveTweed there are plenty of people around the world who can not spare $2k

Comment: There are also plenty of people who do not have automatic blinds in their homes. What's your point?

Comment: @DaveTweed the point is that you're trying to make the best out of what you've got. The point of asking is to learn, not to be told that your skillset is not matched for the job, your negativity is not appreciated, please feel free to not respond.

Comment: For what it's worth, I know quite a lot about electricity and electronics (I'm a professional working in electrical engineering, but not a licensed engineer), and I'm pretty familiar with the sorts of things that would need to be done to build a safe power supply, and _I_ wouldn't try to do it because I'm afraid I'd accidentally kill myself. If you really want to learn something, then buy a UL listed power supply and then read about how to convert that DC voltage to a different DC voltage, or how to control a motor using PWM.

Comment: I would feel free not to respond, except that your proposed actions will put other people at risk, starting with your own family, and ending with any future owners of your house. If you want to learn something new, you start with the basics and work your way up from there. You don't dive into the deep end with a non-isolated mains-powered project!

Comment: The motors are available easily but you'll need gears, limit switches, mounting hardware and enclosures to make them work on top of the electrical controls. I suggest you get an adjustable power supply so you can play with the mechanical side of the project then worry about the permanent supply when you've figured out what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do NOT do what you are suggesting!

You are planning to connect uninsulated motors, to the mains, with no safety barrier or protection.  This is extremely dangerous.

12V & 24V power supplies, complying with local safety standards, are availability at minimum cost for a wide variety of sources.  Use these instead.

As an aside, the resistor in your circuit is to discharge the capacitor, not to carry the main current.  The current is limited by the capacitor whose AC impedance would be given by \$1/(2.π.f.C)\$ .

You would also need a reverse diode (in parallel with the first diode and motor) to allow the capacitor to discharge during alternate half-cycles.

Comment: I didn't know there's Aprils fools day. (@php_nub_qq)